# How can I query data in an OLAP cube (without using Excel)

Tags: mysql, database, excel, olap-cube

I have access to a (confidential) OLAP data cube which I can open as a PivotTable in Excel. However, I want to query the data directly, so that I can analyse it more fully in multi-dimensions.  It would be ideal if I could get the data into a database file (not sure this is possible).

Can I open the .cub file in another application (MySQL database or similar), so that I can query the data?

Or can I query it in Excel (without the PivotTable)?

Comment: I solved this using the R statistics package. <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36456123/using-x4r-package-in-r-to-connect-to-an-ssas-local-data-cube/37569071#37569071">See the solution here</a>.

Answer (score 0):

You can use new functions in the Oracle SQL if that is the RDBMS you're using for storing the Dataset of your project.

Comment: It will be very useful if we know what sort of RDBMS or DB you're using for the storage.

Comment: I have no personal access to the creation software.  I am simply handed the data cube "as is".  I assume the original database is much larger than the data given in the cube.  I just want to see the raw data in these files.  I do not have access to Oracle software.